# Do html elements have properties built in?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about the following piece of Javascript code, it is very basic.

```
    var elNote = document.getElementById('note'); 
    elNote.TextContent = 'Hello';
```

I am new to Javascript and would like to know what is going on here. My book will most likely explain it later, but I would like to learn now.

It is my understanding that elNote gets assigned the html element named note.
My question is if html elements have built in properties, since we select the Property TextConent from the element note. It is also my understanding that elements such as note, are NODES. Does Javascript create and "inject" properties into elements so that they can be modified. I don't know, I'm really trying to think what is going on. thanks.

Comment: what is textContent?

Comment: HTML elements *do* have properties, yes. Some properties only apply to certain element types, e.g., only form fields have a `.value` property.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a loosely typed language, it assigns properties and related methods to the nodes when DOM is defined and its properties vary browser to browser and tier versions.
as far as TextContent is concerned it is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) 
These properties are specific to the type of nodes like 
document it self is also a node but it is a top level node and it does not contains properties like innerText etc.
For more deep understanding of Document Object Model please refer this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

Summing up:

The W3C DOM and WHATWG DOM standards form the basis of the DOM implemented in most modern browsers. Many browsers offer extensions beyond the standard, so care must be exercised when using them on the web where documents may be accessed by various browsers with different DOMs. Copied from [this source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) It looks like DOM is defined by Browsers in the form of javascript **readable / accessible objects** and their properties vary browser to browser.

Comment: So these properties and methods are assigned to the node by Javascript, instead of coming from the DOM itself. In other words, methods like getelementbyId are javascript methods not dom methods?thanks

Comment: Please have this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/introduction.html) too

Comment: I read up on a couple of pages. So if I am correct DOM is sort of an API. It defines the properties and methods used to access a HTML element. In other words the getbyid method is a method of the DOM, not javascript. But javascript can use it to store and retrieve something. Is this correct?

Comment: A language can use and manipulate anything which is defined under its memory section. So can we say javascript is  a DOM language as it can maipulate it?

Comment: Does this mean it is a javascript method and not a dom method

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use for example:

```
elNote.textContent = 'Hello world'; // For raw text content
elNote.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello</h1> world'; // For raw text content
elNote.value = 123; // Tipically for <input> and <button> tags value
```